# where do I find downloads for other flavors such as Ubuntu Studio, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc?

Tags: xubuntu, kubuntu, ubuntu-gnome

Where do I find downloads for other flavors such as Ubuntu Studio, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc?  I want to install in a VM and get the error that says the video will have a hard time with the unity desktop.  So I'd like to use the classic gnome desktop or any that won't give me that problem.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Any suggestion for a flavor that doesn't give me that error about unity desktop?  Ultimately I want to install Odoo 9 in that VM and I want to not have a difficult time with the install process or the pre-reqs.

Answer (score 1):

You can download then from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/  or

from their own sites: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours

Answer (score 0):

The big list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Ubuntu_(operating_system)_derivatives

The official list:

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours

The Ubuntu wiki list:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives

Source: A quick search for "Ubuntu derivatives list."

Answer (score 0):

When I created a Live USB stick yesterday, using Unetbootin there is a place there where you can choose your flavour from a long drop down list.

Also listed on their download site here
[http://unetbootin.github.io/]

Hope this helps
Cheers Maia